# Find the approximate location of android device using only internet not GPS

Tags: android, geolocation

I want to find the approximate location of the android device using only internet, because I don't want user to feel the overhead of having the location on all the time which also drains out the battery, Over internet search I found people suggesting to use GPS for more accurate results, but it is ok for me, even if I get approximate location using internet, I have seen there is a term network location, can some one share a code snippet that would help me.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to ask for [LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

```
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener(){
          public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
            //Do you stuff here
          }
locManager .requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener );
```

*EDIT*

You need to ask for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission.
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION use cell towers to get location not GPS

Comment: You will have to use ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission which use cell towers to get location